# converting table view using pivot query

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I have following structure of table .

```
S_ID  S_Desc  L_ID  L_desc
1     C#      10    Beginner
2     C#      20    Moderate
3     C#      30    Advanced
4     C#      10    Beginner
5     VB      10    Beginner
6     C#      20    Moderate
7     VB      30    Advanced
```

I want following output

```
S_Desc  Beginner  Moderate  Advanced
C#      12        10         10
VB      10         2         14
```

I have written following query but it is not running correctly.

```
Select *
    From
    (
        Select S_Desc,L_Desc From SkillSet
    )as Source_Table
    Pivot
    (
        Count(*) For L_Desc in ([Beginner],[Moderate],[Advanced])   
    ) as Pivot_Table
```

Comment: What do you mean by not running correctly? Do you get an error or the output is not as required?

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Try `Count(S_Desc)` instead of `Count(*)`

Comment: Replace COUNT(*) with COUNT(NotNullColumn)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `L_ID` for Count not `*` in `Pivot` and also Include Column in `L_ID` in Upper part of Query

Try this

```
Select * From
(
    Select S_Desc,L_Desc,L_ID From SkillSet
)as Source_Table
Pivot
(
    Count(L_ID) For 
    L_Desc in ([Beginner],[Moderate],[Advanced])   
) as Pivot_Table
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/48e88/2)**

Answer (score 0):

Please check with following query,

```
Select *
From
(
    Select S_Desc,L_Desc From SkillSet
)as Source_Table
Pivot
(
    Count(L_Desc) For L_Desc in ([Beginner],[Moderate],[Advanced])   
) as Pivot_Table
```